# Why does Eureka Server set up shows Whitelabel Error Page..?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

Hi I am trying to set up Eureka Server for Feign Call I have added POM.xml and application.yml files and when I run the eureka Spring Application the output is printing in the terminal and when I try to run the localhost:8761 in website Whitelabel Error Page error occurs

my POM.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.yml

```html
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
server:
  port: 8761
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv0qr.png)

How to solve Whitelabel Error Page.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.